# Show 'upgrade your browser' modal on every page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to show a customized 'upgrade your browser' modal dialog to users if they visit any page on  my website from an old browser.

I know how to detect the browser but - I cannot figure out where to put the code to show the modal and how to do it. Can ApplicationController before_filter render a js that calls .modal('show')? Any other way? Pure js?

Answer (score 2):

This would be most appropriately solved using Javascript.

- Detect the browser feature you need using Modernizr
- If the Modernizr test fails, display a popover of some kind

Add modernizr.js to your project and insert this javascript into your application.js:

```
Modernizr.load([
    {
        test: Modernizr.cssgradients,
        nope: function () { alert('Sorry, your browser does not support a required feature of this site. Please upgrade or use another browser.'); }
    }
]);
```

Change "Modernizr.cssgradients" to whatever feature you need.

If you don't want to have this as a bare "alert", you could use something like [noty.js](http://needim.github.com/noty/), replacing the `alert` method above with:

```
noty({text: 'Sorry, your browser does not support a required feature of this site. Please upgrade or use another browser.'});
```

Comment: Thanks that's helpful. I would like to use a bootstrap modal for consistency across other modals on my site. I will check out Modernizr.

Comment: Sure - there's a Bootstrap modal which will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Place the div/modal in your layout file (app/views/layouts/application.html.erb, most likely), and wrap it in a rails conditional based on your needs, like so:

```
<body>
    ....
    <% if (old_browsers.include?(current_browser) %>
        <div class="old-browser-modal">
            ....
        </div>
    <% end %>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but where do I call modal.show? if condition on every page.load?