# Stop users with Internet Explorer 8 and below

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

my question is : how can i stop IE8 and blow ( IE7 , IE6 , ... ) users.

I want to stop IE8 and blow users to see my website and then show a page to them and tell them upgrade their browser or use other modern browsers !

anybody know how can i do this ??!

Much thanks !

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you searched for other stackoverflow questions that might answer this yet?

Comment: I suppose that's less annoying than the sites that used to tell you to use IE when you were already using a perfectly good browser, but still seems like a Bad Idea.

Comment: I suggest using a tool like Modernizr to detect the specific browser features that you need which are missing in older browsers. Because if you need features in IE>=9, IE8 probably isn't the only old browser you'd have problems with.

Comment: Also, in general, people still using old IE versions probably know by now that they need to upgrade. If they haven't done so already, it's probably because they can't. Telling them they should do so isn't going to help. Best thing to do is just let them see your site to the best capability of their browser. If that means it's broken, then so be it.

Comment: with this script you can detect the browser and version, then you can redirect navigator.sayswho= (function(){
var N= navigator.appName, ua= navigator.userAgent, tem;
var M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];
return M;
})();

Comment: I enjoy this approach: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-18440979

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show 'upgrade your browser' modal on every page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807498/show-upgrade-your-browser-modal-on-every-page)

Comment: Hi everyone. thanks a lot. i know that's not a good idea but i just want to know. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to go: http://browser-update.org

Comment: I think this would be a good Idea so far. There will be a Notificationbar and a Link to follow to get more information about "How to update".

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your header

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = function() { window.location = "http://mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/" };</script><![endif]-->
```